# iPhone: View/Close button click action on push notification message dialog

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

Could anyone please tell me how to handle push notification dialog's view and close button click from my application? I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313406/push-notification-and-view-button-actioniphone-sdk-apns) thread which says to handle it in ViewDidLoad but when I click View button, this method doesn't get invoked. I want to do take user to some particular view on View button click and record the Close button click on my Server. So basically I want to know what happens when this button(s) clicked? I have gone through Apple docs but it nothing say about these actions. Any documentation and/or code sample would be really greatful.

Thanks.

Comment: You should read Apple's doc (or the thread you referred) again. User either accept push notification and then your app get to process it or simply ignore and your app get nothing.

Comment: I have read everything thoroghly and understood most of the things. As I said while debugging, I have noticed that when I click View button, ViewDidLoad doesn't get invoked. Is there anyway to know that user clicked Close button?

Comment: No you didn't. No docs said to look at -viewDidLoad, look at the sample code through the link in your post again, please.

Comment: Aha sorry...by ViewDidLoad, I meant didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. This method doesn't get invoked. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If your app have not yet been launched, you get through didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, or you get didReceiveRemoteNotification

Comment: Got this working. The problem was running my application directly attaching iPhone with XCode editor.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user clicks view then you can catch that action in didFinishLaunchWithOptions method of AppDelegate class. If user clicks close then, there is no way for application to catch that. If your application didn't get the notification in AppDelegate class, then either you forgot to register your app for push notification or you didn't send push notification properly to APNS.